# Context in DotVVM inner ViewModel is null

Tags: c#, mvvm, dotvvm

I am making a DotVVM application, in which I want to display either logout button or login form on every page. Therefore I made custom control that uses ViewModel to handle login, or logout.
Since I want this control on every page I put it inside my .master page.

My DotMaster Page looks like this:

```
@viewModel MyApp.ViewModels.AppViewModelBase, MyApp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>{{value:Title}}</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default">
           ...
           <cc:LoginPanel DataContext="{value: LoginSection}"></cc:LoginPanel>
           ...
       </nav>
       ...
   </body> 
</html>
```

Coresponding ViewModel **AppViewModelBase** looks like this.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DotVVM.Framework.ViewModel;
using MyApp.ViewModels.Login;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
   public class AppViewModelBase : DotvvmViewModelBase
   {
      public string SubpageTitle { get; set; }

      public string Title { get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", LogoText, SubpageTitle); } }

      public LoginSection LoginSection { get; set; } = new LoginSection();
      ...
   }
}
```

My **LoginSection** ViewModel also inherits from **DotvvmViewModelBase**, the problem is, the Context property of **LoginSection** is never filled and remains null. 
Am I supposed to set the Context of inner ViewModels manualy? I also noticed that Context of AppViewModelBase is not set in it's base constructor, but somewhere later on.

What is the best practice for this use case?

Answer (score 1):

In current version of DotVVM (0.8.6-pre), the Context property of the page viewmodel is set by the framework (before the `Init` method is called).

However, if the viewmodel contains other objects, those Context is not set (mostly because of performance reasons - we'd have to browse the viewmodel using reflection and analyze each property).

For now, I recommend to pass the Context property to the child object in the `Init` phase.

```
public override Task Init()
{
    LoginSection.Context = Context;
}
```

However, in future versions we are planning add some mechanism to inject these framework objects automatically.